# Message 2100 when run sql*loader from UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, sql-loader

I have .sh file with the next content:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo -------- uploader.sh v 0.1 --------
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/
export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH

sqlldr userid=PR/0611@database control=control_file.ctl LOG=fb_log.log errors=100
```

So, i want to run sql loader and upload data. When i run uploader.sh i receive the next message from unix:

> Message 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS,
>   facility=ULMessage 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS,
>   facility=UL

I've read about it and made conclusion that the problem is in the enviroment variables. Could you help me with desision of this mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change this line

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/
```

to

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1
```

and see it

also check if you have  ORAUS.MSB on your system

Comment: 'sqlldr: command not found'
after changing. Also I am not an admin on the server machine.

Comment: better!!!  but now there is another type of mistake:  SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Wed May 2 17:08:12 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: start listener using `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start`

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but I had a similar issue on Windows today, found lots of posts referring to ORAUS.MSB, but I already had that. To resolve I copied ULUS.MSB from another machine - might help someone.

Comment: thanks, this helped me out. I'm currently looking at a minimized version of the oracle image in https://github.com/diemobiliar/minimized-oraclexe-image and they removed sqlldr from the image but I need it to do some initial db setup. 

it looks like this was the missing piece.

Comment: where can i get ORAUS.MSB file ? I am also getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Declare the environment variables inside the shell that will be executed and which makes the call in sqlldr. It worked for me.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +vx

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/mesg
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export ORACLE_HOME
export PATH

sqlldr userid=USER/PWD@BANK control=control_file.ctl LOG=fb_log.log errors=100
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same message after performing a client installation of Oracle 19c for Linux. While attempting to run `sqlldr`, with all above environment variables set as described. The `oraus.msg` and `oraus.msb` files were under the installation as well, located under `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/mesg/`.

My issue was that I had chosen the "Runtime Client" installation option during the install wizard.  The `sqlldr` is evidently part of the "Administrator Client" installation option.  Once I re-installed the Oracle Client software with Administrator Client option, `sqlldr` ran as expected.